# Merge two columns of a gzipped file and replace the merged column with another column

Tags: linux, awk, merge

I have a gzipped file which looks like this :

```
 1 rs571093408 rs571093408 13380 C G
```

I want to merge the first and fourth column with `:` inbetween and replace the second column with the new content, so the output looks like this :

```
 1 1:13380 rs571093408 13380 C G
```

The input is a gzipped file and I want the ouput file to be gzipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print content of a gzipped file with the command `zcat`.

So printing source file `file1.gz`:

```
$ zcat file1.gz
1 rs571093408 rs571093408 13380 C G
2 rs200000002 rs222222222 12222 D E
3 rs300000003 rs333333333 13333 F K
```

One liner to execute:

```
$ zcat file1.gz|awk '{print $1" "$1":"$4,$3,$4,$5,$6}'|gzip > file2.gz
```

Printing the result file `file2.gz` content:

```
$ zcat file2.gz
1 1:13380 rs571093408 13380 C G
2 2:12222 rs222222222 12222 D E
3 3:13333 rs333333333 13333 F K
```

---

**Updated. Adding improved version based on comment below:**

```
$ zcat file1.gz|awk '{$2=$1":"$4}1'|gzip > file2.gz
```

Comment: `awk '{$2=$1":"$4}1'`

Comment: Thank you Ed! I did have thousands of columns!

Answer (score -1):

The final code I used was:

```
zcat file.gz | awk '{$2=$1":"$4}1' | gzip > new_file.gz | mv new_file.gz file.gz
```

`mv new_file.gz file.gz` in the end replaces the new file with the old one.

Comment: That last `|` immediately before the `mv`  should be `&&`. The pipe (`|`) is doing nothing useful while the test for success (`&&`) will stop you from wiping out your input file if there's a failure before the `&&`.

Comment: Thank you so much Ed! It did indeed wipe out my input file the first time I tried...there was an error in the code. I worked fine when I modified it and tried it again.

Comment: I have another question. Once I edit the files, the word count using wc -l reduces by a few thousand per file. Is this normal or is something going wrong here?

Comment: If you have another question then.... ask another question :-). Post a new question with it's own concise, testable sample input/output to get help. Accepting your own answer which is just a copy of [@Yurko's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565589/133219) to the question you asked isn't great etiquette for this forum btw.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to concise everything into one point so its easier for others to see , rather than reading the entire text and finding the answer in the middle. Didn't realize it un-accepted @Yurko's answer. Sorry about that. Error corrected.

Comment: If you want to provide some kind of summary at the end of a question, you can just edit your question to provide that info at the bottom of it rather than posting your own separate answer.